# php split half-width & full-width sentence

Tags: php, regex

I need to split my text into an array at every period, exclamation and question mark.

Example with a full-width period and exclamation mark:

```
$string = "日本語を勉強しているみんなを応援したいです。一緒に頑張りましょう！";
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 日本語を勉強しているみんなを応援したいです。
    [1] => 一緒に頑張りましょう！ )
```

I need the same code to work with half-width.

Example with a mix of full-width and half-width:
    $string = "Hi. I am Bob! Nice to meet you. 日本語を勉強しています。Do you understand me?";

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Hi.
    [1] => I am Bob!
    [2] => Nice to meet you.
    [3] => 日本語を勉強しています。
    [4] => Do you understand me? )
```

I suck at regular expressions and can't figure out a solution nor find one.

I tried:

```
$string = preg_split('(.*?[。？！])', $string);
```

Comment: I can't see how full-width and half-width are any different in regards to what PHP needs to do with the string.

Comment: PHP doesn't see . and 。as the same or ! and ！. Same with ? and ？.

Comment: And if they are all in the list delimiters there is no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you forgot your delimiters (most commonly a slash).

You can split on `\pP` (a unicode punctuation - remember the `u` modifier meaning unicode):

You can see the rest of the special unicode characters [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

```
<?php

$str = 'Hi. I am Bob! Nice to meet you. 日本語を勉強しています。Do you understand me?';

$array = preg_split('/(?<=\pP)\s*/u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($array);
```

The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` is there to make sure that we don't include an empty match if your last character is punctuation.

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi.
    [1] => I am Bob!
    [2] => Nice to meet you.
    [3] => 日本語を勉強しています。
    [4] => Do you understand me?
)
```

**Regex autopsy**:

- `/` - *the start delimiter - this must also come at the end before our modifiers*
- `(?<=\pP)` - *a positive lookbehind matching `\pP` (a unicode punctuation - we could just use `\pP`, but then the punctuation would not be included in our final string - a positive lookbehind includes it)*
- `\s*` - *a white space character matched 0 to infinity times - this is to make sure that we don't include the white space after the punctuation*
- `/u` - *the end delimiter (`/`) and our modifier (`u` meaning "unicode")*

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/157393)

Your first sentence would result in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 日本語を勉強しているみんなを応援したいです。
    [1] => 一緒に頑張りましょう！
)
```

---

**Please note that this includes *all* punctuation including commas.**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is my sentence,
    [1] => and it is very nice.
)
```

This can be fixed by using a negative lookbehind in front of our positive lookbehind:

```
/(?<![,、;；"”\'’｀`])(?<=\pP)\s*/u
```

Comment: h2ooooooo, thank you however this seems to split the string at commas too. I am only looking for sentence ending punctuation. In this case a . ? and !. Example: https://eval.in/157394

Comment: very nice answer. much more clever than what I started writing :) +1

Comment: Looking at the link you provided for all unicode characters, I noticed that final punctuation is Pf. How do I include that? I tried $string = preg_split('/(?<=\pPf)\s*/u', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); but it didn't work.

Comment: @BryseMeijer Change the regex to `/(?<!,)(?<=\pP)\s*/u` where we include a *negative* lookbehind. [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/157412). It seems like `pF` does not include regular punctuation.

Comment: \p{Pf} didn't work at all. Your example with the negative lookbehind breaks on full-width. I changed it to `/(?<!,|、)(?<=\pP)\s*/u`. https://eval.in/157424 This satisfies my original question now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BryseMeijer Yeah as I edited, apparently all our regular punctuation (commas and dots are in the same "category") and is only matched by `\p{pO}` meaning "other punctuation". Pretty useless if you ask me.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the following: ` /(?<!,|、|;|；|"|”|'|’|`|｀)(?<=\pP)\s*/u` You can also write `$exclude = array(
  ',',
  '、',
  ';',
  '；',
  '"',
  '”',
  '\'',
  '’',
  '`',
  '｀'
);` with `$string = preg_split('/(?<!'.implode('|', $exclude).')(?<=\pP)\s*/u', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`   https://eval.in/157439

Comment: @BryseMeijer If you use a character group (`[abc]`) it's so much easier than `a|b|c` specially if you have more characters. I've updated the answer with it. Thank you for your update.